# PgSQL insert into select after cast

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with many columns stored as text. These columns have  information which i am planning to cast and copy the data into a fresh table with the same column names but with correct data types ( float8 )

I tested the SELECT with CAST operator "::" and it works fine. All the columns are being converted as you can see in the picture

[image]

However , when I uncomment the INSERT statement ( above it ) to start writing in the target table, it throws an error. The target table has identical column names and only float8 column types.

[image]

The expression from the source table is indeed of type text but i am using the cast operator so why does it not work like before when only running the SELECT statement?

My query below:

```
INSERT INTO "PM"."new_VM_gcell_evolution_hourly_BSC"
(select 
"CR3120:Channel_Assignment_Failures_All_Channels_Busy_or_Channel"::float8,
"DL_Mean_Quality"::float8,
"A312Ca:Failed_Assignments_during_MTC_on_the_A_Interface_Includi"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_4number"::float8,
"A3129C:Failed_Assignments_First_Assignment,_Assignment_Timed_Ou"::float8,
"R3120C:Channel_Assignment_Failures_All_Channels_Busy_or_Channel"::float8,
"TSs_Interf_B5"::float8,
"R3120D:Channel_Assignment_Failures_All_Channels_Busy_or_Channel"::float8,
"HO_Out_Internal_Succ_Rate"::float8,
"CH_Req_Protocol_Undefinednbnumber"::float8,
"UL_Drop_Congnumber"::float8,
"Timing_Adv"::float8,
"DL_Qual"::float8,
"A3100C:Assignment_Requests_TCHH_Only"::float8,
"MS_to_BTS_max_distance"::float8,
"TSs_Interf_B2"::float8,
"UL_Qual"::float8,
"UL_Drop_EDGE_Rate"::float8,
"Avg_BTS_Power_Level_AMR"::float8,
"DL_Drop_N3105number"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_2_R"::float8,
"CH_Req_CallReestabnbnumber"::float8,
"TCH_Drops_cause_Timing_Advance"::float8,
"TCH_Drops_per_Erlang"::float8,
"UL_Drop_Flushnumber"::float8,
"A312F:Number_of_Assignment_Failures_No_Abis_Resource_Available"::float8,
"UL_Drop_GPRS_Rate"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_3number"::float8,
"Call_Drop_rate"::float8,
"DL_Fail_Assingnumber"::float8,
"SDCCH_Radio_Failures"::float8,
"HO_Cmd_UL_Qual"::float8,
"UL/DL_RxQualnumber"::float8,
"UL/DL_RxLevnumber"::float8,
"UL_Fail_EDGE_Rate"::float8,
"Call_Drop_Total"::float8,
"HO_Out_Succ_Rate"::float8,
"Date"::text,
"A3127E:Failed_Assignments_during_Call_Reestablishment_on_the_Um"::float8,
"UL_Drop_N3103number"::float8,
"Configured_TCH"::float8,
"SDCCH_Drop_Call_Rate_only_LU"::float8,
"A312M:Failed_Assignments_Reconnection_to_Old_Channels,_No_Chann"::float8,
"SDCCH_Blocking_Rate"::float8,
"TCH_Drops_cause_DL_FER"::float8,
"TCH_Fail_rate"::float8,
"DL_Drop_Preemnumber"::float8,
"FR_Traffic_totalErl"::float8,
"DL_Congnumber"::float8,
"TCH_Assign_Unsuccnumber"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_0_R"::float8,
"DL_Drop_GPRS_Rate"::float8,
"HR_TraficErl"::float8,
"SDCCH_Cong_Rate"::float8,
"Abis_and_Ater_Interface_Anlysistimes"::float8,
"A3100B:Assignment_Requests_TCHF_Only"::float8,
"AS4300D:Mean_Uplink_Level_during_Radio_Link_Failure_SDCCHdB"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_89number"::float8,
"TCH_Drops_cause_DownQual"::float8,
"SDCCH_Drop_RxLev"::float8,
"Max_UL_Pwr_Duration"::float8,
"nsp_Channel_Req_LUnumber"::float8,
"TCH_HR_Initialy_Config"::float8,
"HO_Inc_Cong_Rate"::float8,
"DL_RxLev_avgdBm"::float8,
"TCH_Assign_Requestsnumber"::float8,
"A312K:Failed_Assignments_First_Assignment,_No_Channel_Available"::float8,
"Call_Drop_TCH_Quality_Rate"::float8,
"AMR_HR_TraficErl"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_67_R"::float8,
"UL_Fail_MSnumber"::float8,
"Time"::text,
"TCH_Drops_cause_UpLevel"::float8,
"AMR_FR_TraficErl"::float8,
"TCH_FR_Initialy_Config"::float8,
"UL_Drop_N3101number"::float8,
"DL_FERnumber"::float8,
"SDCCH_Drop_Call_Rate_wo_LU"::float8,
"DL_Mean_StrengthdB"::float8,
"Call_Drop_Abis"::float8,
"SDCCH_Initialy_Confignumber"::float8,
"Call_Drop_TCH_RxLev_Rate"::float8,
"TA_Meannumber"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_67number"::float8,
"AS3240NA:Average_MS_Power_Level_of_NonAMR_Call"::float8,
"Load"::float8,
"A3129Q:Failed_Assignments_Reconnection_to_Old_Channels,_Timer_E"::float8,
"CH_Request_11_bit"::float8,
"AS4340D:Mean_TA_during_Radio_Link_Failure_SDCCH"::float8,
"S4210A:Uplink_Interference_Indication_Messages_SDCCH"::float8,
"UL_FERnumber"::float8,
"A3129P:Failed_Assignments_Reconnection_to_Old_Channels,_Timer_E"::float8,
"K3003A:Successful_SDCCH_Seizures_Call_Type"::float8,
"CH_Req_LAUnbnumber"::float8,
"SDCCH_Drop_Rate"::float8,
"GBSC"::text,
"CS_CSSR_with_SDCCH_blocks_wo_LU"::float8,
"A312Aa:Failed_Assignments_during_MOC_on_the_A_Interface_Includi"::float8,
"Avg_BTS_Power_Level"::float8,
"R3120A:Channel_Assignment_Failures_All_Channels_Busy_or_Channel"::float8,
"A312S:Failed_Assignments_Signaling_Channel"::float8,
"SD_Fail_MoC"::float8,
"UL_RxQual_avg"::float8,
"Call_Drop_HO"::float8,
"AS4330D:Mean_Downlink_Quality_during_Radio_Link_Failure_SDCCH"::float8,
"CH_Req_Emerg_Callsnbnumber"::float8,
"UL_RxQualnumber"::float8,
"UL_Fail_OtherCausenumber"::float8,
"A312Da:Failed_Assignments_during_Emergency_Call_on_the_A_Interf"::float8,
"UL_Drop_Preemnumber"::float8,
"TCH_Drops_cause_UpDown_FER"::float8,
"AS4320D:Mean_Downlink_Level_during_Radio_Link_Failure_SDCCHdB"::float8,
"A3129O:Failed_Assignments_First_Assignment,_Directed_Retry_Time"::float8,
"Max_DL_Pwr_Duration"::float8,
"UL_Drop_Suspendnumber"::float8,
"TCH_Assign_Congestionnumber"::float8,
"Transmission_Resource_Analysistimes"::float8,
"HO_Out_RxQual_rate"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_1013number"::float8,
"A3129I:Failed_Assignments_Invalid_State"::float8,
"DL_Fail_OtherCausenumber"::float8,
"CR3129:Channel_Assignment_Failures_All_Channels_Busy_or_Channel"::float8,
"HO_Inc_Successnumber"::float8,
"A3129B:Failed_Assignments_First_Assignment,_Terrestrial_Resourc"::float8,
"Trafic_totalErl"::float8,
"nsp_urban_TA_1463all_R"::float8,
"HO_Out_RxQualnumber"::float8,
"DL_RxQualnumber"::float8,
"HO_Inc_Succ_Rate"::float8,
"SDCCH_Fail_Rate"::float8,
"SDCCH_Non_Radio_Drops"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_0number"::float8,
"A3129E:Failed_Assignments_CIC_Unavailable"::float8,
"nsp_CH_Request_PSnumber"::float8,
"TCH_Assign_Unsucc_rate"::float8,
"Call_Drop_Radio"::float8,
"EFR_TraficErl"::float8,
"A312L:Failed_Assignments_Reconnection_to_Old_Channels,_No_Chann"::float8,
"TCH_Drops_cause_DownLevel"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_5number"::float8,
"Abnormal_Terminals_Analysistimes"::float8,
"HO_Inc_Congnumber"::float8,
"CSSR_Rate"::float8,
"M3020C:Call_Drops_on_SDCCHQuality"::float8,
"RH333:Handover_Drop_Rate_of_TCH"::float8,
"UL_Drop_EDGE_Abisnumber"::float8,
"A3129J:Failed_Assignments_Invalid_Message"::float8,
"TCH_Availability"::float8,
"UL_Level"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_4_R"::float8,
"UL_Drop_OtherCausenumber"::float8,
"HR_Traffic_Rate"::float8,
"DL_Level"::float8,
"CH_Request_8_bit"::float8,
"UL_Fail_MS_Assingnumber"::float8,
"DL_Fail_BSC_Commandnumber"::float8,
"A3129R:Failed_Assignments_Reconnection_to_Old_Channels,_Reconne"::float8,
"UL_Fail_BSC_Commandnumber"::float8,
"DL_Drop_Suspendnumber"::float8,
"nsp_urban_TA_1463allnumber"::float8,
"Direct_Retry"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_89_R"::float8,
"CH_Req_PSnbnumber"::float8,
"A3129N:Failed_Assignments_Reconnection_to_Old_Channels,_Terrest"::float8,
"A312A:Failed_Assignments_First_Assignment,_No_Channel_Available"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_2number"::float8,
"DL_RxQual_avg"::float8,
"UL_Mean_StrengthdB"::float8,
"DL_Drop_EDGE_Rate"::float8,
"A3129T:Failed_Assignments_No_Ater_Resource_Available"::float8,
"TSs_Interf_B1"::float8,
"A3129D:Failed_Assignments_Reconnection_to_Old_Channels,_Reconne"::float8,
"nsp_Channel_Req_MOCnumber"::float8,
"UL_Fail_GPRS_Rate"::float8,
"S4210B:Downlink_Interference_Indication_Messages_SDCCH"::float8,
"R3120E:Channel_Assignment_Failures_All_Channels_Busy_or_Channel"::float8,
"HO_Inc_Failnumber"::float8,
"DL_Drop_Flushnumber"::float8,
"S3655:Number_of_configured_TRXs_in_a_cell"::float8,
"TCH_Drops_cause_UpDown_Qual"::float8,
"CR3005:Number_of_Initially_Configured_Channels_Static_PDTCH_Sup"::float8,
"UL/DL_FERnumber"::float8,
"SDCCH_Blocking_"::float8,
"HO_Out_InterRAT_Succ_Rate"::text,
"CM30E:Call_Drops_on_SDCCH_Location_Updating"::float8,
"AS4310D:Mean_Uplink_Quality_during_Radio_Link_Failure_SDCCH"::float8,
"UL_Congnumber"::float8,
"TAnumber"::float8,
"Configured_SDCCH"::float8,
"Othernumber"::float8,
"TCH_Assign_Fail_Radionumber"::float8,
"HO_Out_Internal_Req_Nb"::float8,
"SDCCH_Cong_Nbnumber"::float8,
"UL_Mean_Quality"::float8,
"HO_Out_External_Req_Nb"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_1013_R"::float8,
"SDCCH_Drops_wo_LU"::float8,
"Call_Drop_TCH_Qualitynumber"::float8,
"A3100A:Assignment_Requests_Signaling_Channel_TCH"::float8,
"Better_Cell"::float8,
"Call_Drop_TCH_RxLevnumber"::float8,
"nsp_Channel_Req_MTCnumber"::float8,
"DL_Fail_EDGE_Rate"::float8,
"ZTR104B:Call_Drop_Rate_on_SDCCH_Call_Type"::float8,
"Call_Drop_no_MR"::float8,
"DL_Drop_Congnumber"::float8,
"HO_Inc_InterRAT_reqnumber"::float8,
"TCH_Assign_Cong_rate"::float8,
"HO_Inc_Fail_Rate"::float8,
"TCH_Assign_Fail_sp_ver_unav"::float8,
"HO_Inc_InterRAT_unsucc"::float8,
"A3170A:Number_of_Completed_TCH_Assignments_CSFB_MOC"::float8,
"HO_Inc_Unsucc_Rate"::float8,
"TSs_Interf_B4"::float8,
"A3100K:Assignment_Requests_Signaling_Channel_SDCCH"::float8,
"TCH_Drops_cause_UpDown_Level"::float8,
"SDCCH_Fail_Nbnumber"::float8,
"TCH_Non_Radio_Drops"::float8,
"DL_Fail_MSnumber"::float8,
"HO_Cmd_DL_Qual"::float8,
"DL_Drop_OtherCausenumber"::float8,
"SMS_on_SDCCH"::float8,
"FERnumber"::float8,
"HO_Inc_Reqnumber"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_3_R"::float8,
"M3020D:Call_Drops_on_SDCCHOther"::float8,
"HO_Out_External_Succ_Rate"::float8,
"M3020A:Call_Drops_on_SDCCHTA"::float8,
"TCH_Assign_Fail_Radio_rate"::float8,
"CR3001:Number_of_Initially_Configured_Channels_Static_PDCH"::float8,
"HR_Traffic_totalErl"::float8,
"CH_Req_MTCnbnumber"::float8,
"SDCCH_Drop_RxQual"::float8,
"UL_RxLev_avgdBm"::float8,
"CH_Req_MOCnbnumber"::float8,
"SDCCH_Dropnumber"::float8,
"A3169A:Failed_Assignments_Um_Cause"::float8,
"A3129H:Failed_Assignments_Clear_Commands_Sent_By_MSC"::float8,
"TCH_Radio_Drops"::float8,
"HO_Out_InterRAT_Req_Nb"::float8,
"HO_Inc_InterRAT_succnumber"::float8,
"DL_Drop_Abisnumber"::float8,
"TCH_Drops_cause_UL_FER"::float8,
"UL_RxLevelnumber"::float8,
"nsp_CH_Request_CSnumber"::float8,
"A3170B:Number_of_Completed_TCH_Assignments_CSFB_MTC"::float8,
"A3129F:Failed_Assignments_CIC_Allocated"::float8,
"DL_Fail_GPRS_Rate"::float8,
"M3020B:Call_Drops_on_SDCCHReceived_Level"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_1number"::float8,
"SDCCH_Availability"::float8,
"Call_Drop_forced_HO"::float8,
"SDCCH_Drop_Others"::float8,
"Call_Drop_Equip."::float8,
"CH_Req_PS"::float8,
"SDCCH_Drop_Call_Rate"::float8,
"TCH_Drops_cause_UpQual"::float8,
"CH_Req_LMU_Reservednbnumber"::float8,
"DL_RxLevnumber"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_1_R"::float8,
"A312Ea:Failed_Assignments_during_Call_Reestablishment_on_the_A_"::float8,
"TSs_Interf_B3"::float8,
"SDCCH_Drop_TimingAdvance"::float8,
"Avg_BTS_Power_Level_NAMR"::float8,
"TCH_Drops_cause_Other"::float8,
"FR_TraficErl"::float8,
"Avg_MS_Power_Level"::float8,
"HO_Outgoing_Requestsnumber"::float8,
"A3129G:Failed_Assignments_A_Interface_Failure"::float8,
"CH_Req_LAU"::float8,
"nsp_Urban_TA_5_R"::float8,
"HO_Inc_Unsuccessnumber"::float8,
"AS3240A:Average_MS_Power_Level_of_AMR_Call"::float8
from "PM"."VM_gcell_evolution_hourly_BSC_recovered")
```

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Usually i post the code but here i have a table with 270 columns . Wouldn't it be hard to read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says "column is of type double but expression is of type text" so what's really happening is that it's trying to insert one of the expressions where you cast to ::text into a column that is of type double.

If the problem was converting from text to double, you'd get a different message. Besides, the SELECT worked fine, which means it didn't encounter any text data that it couldn't convert to double.

Since you don't specify the target table columns in your INSERT, and you have so many of them, most likely you missed a column or got the order wrong.

Honestly if the table has 270 columns and they have the same name in the source and destination tables, you should really generate the query using something like python from a list of columns, that will be faster than proofreading the 270 lines...

Comment: it's strange because the column data types I am casting are those of the target table extracted from the information schema with a one on one maping so normally i should not have a "text to double" missmatch

Comment: Yeah but are they in the correct order? Have you tried adding the columns to the INSERT?

Comment: correct. I have to add the columns explicitly in the insert command. Although the target table has the same columns it  has a different order for them. Now it works